# React: dynamically component with select dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting array of objects from server. ForEach object in that array add
new object from my state, which will be my options in dropdown, and save all that in my state. Then with map render component  with data and dropdown values. Question is, how to change  values in drop for each unique component

```
state = {

        allCampaigns: [],
        inputDropdown: {
            dropDown: {
                elementType: 'select',
                elementConfig: {
                    type: "dropdown",
                    options: [
                        {
                            value: "Update",
                            displayValue: "Update"
                        },
                        {
                            value: "Start",
                            displayValue: "Start"
                        },
                        {
                            value: "Pause",
                            displayValue: "Pause"
                        },
                        {
                            value: "Stop",
                            displayValue: "Stop"
                        },
                        {
                            value: "Delete",
                            displayValue: "Delete"
                        },
                    ],
                },
                value: '',
            }
        },
        choosedCampaign: null,
    }
```

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onInitAllCampaigns(this.props.customerId, 
    this.state.pageNumber, this.state.pageSize);
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.allCampaigns !== this.props.allCampaigns) {
        const allCampaignsFromProps = this.props.allCampaigns;
        const campaignActions = this.state.inputDropdown.dropDown;
        allCampaignsFromProps.forEach(function (action) { 
        action.actionType = campaignActions })
        this.setState({ allCampaigns: allCampaignsFromProps })
    }
}

inputActionType = (event, campaignIndex) => {
    const updatedAllCampaigns = {
        ...this.state.allCampaigns
    }
    const updatedCampaign = {
        ...updatedAllCampaigns[campaignIndex]
    }
    updatedCampaign.actionType.value = event.target.value;
    updatedAllCampaigns[campaignIndex] = updatedCampaign
    this.setState({ allCampaigns: updatedAllCampaigns })
}

currentCampaign = (index) => {
    let campaigns = this.state.allCampaigns
    for (let i = 0; i < campaigns.length; i++) {
        if (i === index) {
            this.setState({ choosedCampaign: campaigns[i] })
        }
    }
}

render() {
    const campaignsArray = [];
    for (let index in this.state.allCampaigns) {
        campaignsArray.push({
            id: index,
            config: this.state.allCampaigns[index]
        })
    }
    <div className={classes.Container}>
      <div className={classes.CamapignsWrapper}>
        {campaignsArray.map((campaign, index) => (
          <UserCampaign
            key={campaign.id}
            campaignKey={campaign.id}
            //Campaign values
            name={campaign.config.name}          
            onClick={this.currentCampaign.bind(this,index)}
            // Input values
            keyInput={index}
            inputTypes={campaign.config.actionType.elementConfig.type}
            elementType={campaign.config.actionType.elementType}
            elementConfig={campaign.config.actionType.elementConfig}
            value={campaign.config.actionType.value}
            changed={(event) => this.inputActionType(event, campaign.id)}
            classNameInput={classes.InputDropDown}>
      </UserCampaign>
```

Currently with all my tries i always change value in all components.

Comment: It's because your selected `value` belongs to the state, so every change in this value will be reflected in all subscribed components. The solution is to move your selected value to the `right` component using it

Comment: Solved. Added own state for component. Thx Mohamed